# calculations using np.arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am really struggling to understand how to perform calculations with **numpy arrays**.

```
myList = open('key_resp.csv')
newList = np.array(myList)

newList2=sorted(newList)

newLists = open("dataSorted.csv",'w')
writer = csv.writer(newLists)
writer.writerow(newList2)

medNumber=np.median(newLists)

fast = newList2[:len(newList2)//2]
slow = newList2[len(newList2)//2:]


dataFast = open("dataFast.csv",'w')
writer = csv.writer(dataFast)
writer.writerow(fast)
```

Now for every value in `dataFast` I want to subtract `medNumber`.

`dataFast.csv` looks like `[0.1] [0.2] [0.3]` in csv file.

Comment: Note that numpy array have a `sort` method. Using `sorted` will convert them to a python `list` and you will loose any advantage of speed/memory you had with the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract in place (without copying the array) doing:

```
dataFast -= np.median(newLists)
```